# How do I convert a String in a different timezone to UTC using Joda-Time

Tags: java, jodatime

I managed to convert a valid date string in a different timezone to [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) as follows.

```
String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
DateTimeFormatter DATETIME_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(DATE_FORMAT);
DateTimeZone dateTimeZone = DateTimeZone.forID("-03:00");
//date is 2000-01-01 00:00:00 -03:00
DateTime date =    DATETIME_FORMATTER.withZone(dateTimeZone).parseDateTime("2000-01-01 00:00:00"));
System.out.println("Current date is: " + date.toString());
//now convert to UTC
DateTime convertedDate = date.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);
System.out.println("Converted date: " + date.toString());
```

The result is

```
Current date is: 2000-01-01T00:00:00.000-03:00
Converted date: 2000-01-01T03:00:00.000Z
```

Is there a shorter/better way of doing this? I want the final date to be a [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) object.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the time zone of any `DateTime` using [withZone()](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withZone%28org.joda.time.DateTimeZone%29). If the input string doesn't specify the time-zone offset then you have to add it as you are doing, so your code is fairly optimal.

Answer (score 0):

One improvement over your example code might be replacing the hard-coded "-3:00" offset with a time zone name. That would allow Joda-Time to make adjustments for any possible [Daylight Saving Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) (DST). See doc for [DateTimeZone.forID()](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html#forID%28java.lang.String%29).

This:

```
DateTimeZone dateTimeZone = DateTimeZone.forID("America/Sao_Paulo");
```

instead of this:

```
DateTimeZone dateTimeZone = DateTimeZone.forID("-03:00");
```

Time Zone list (possibly outdated, read note): 
http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html